# Не открывается сайт в Chrome (исключительно в компьютерной версии)

Tags: google-chrome

Бесконечная загрузка сайта. Ошибок в консоли нету, но при этом в sourse через инспектор кода почему-то нету никаких файлов. Опять-таки, только в компьютерной версии Chrome такая проблема. В мобильной версии Chrome и остальных браузерах всё работает нормально.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: думаю все логично, значит сервер ничего не отдает, возможно что то в htaccess если на апаче работает

Comment: только в Хроме ?

Comment: Всё уже работает. Перезапустили сервер, перезалили файлы и всё заработало. Спасибо всем кто откликнулся.